# Looking for help of Chemfig professional to draw a complex molecule

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

Can someone help me with the complex drawing of iron(II) protoporphyrin IX using `chemfig` or else?
I know this is a bad question but this exceeds my skills by far (i just began using this package) and i don't want to implement it as picture because i want to modify it further with a reaction scheme and `tikz`. Thanks in advance.

[image: the result i want to have]

i got till this:

```
 \chemfig{
   ?[a]-[::+63]*5(
     -N?[b]-(
       -=[::-54]*5(
         -N?[c]=(
           -=[::-54]*5(
             -N?[d]-(
               =-[::-54]*5(
                 =N(-[::-54,1.5]Fe?[b,,thick,dotted]?[c]?[d,,      thick,dotted])
                 -[,,1]?[a]-(-[::-54])=-(-)-
               )
             )
             -(-)=(-[::-60]-[::-60]-(-[::+60]OH)=[::-60]O)-
           )
         )
         -(-[::-60]-[::-60]-(-[::+60]OH)=[::-60]O)=(-)-
       )
     )
     =(-)-(-([::+40]=))=
   )
 }
```

but there is still something to do and i can't get it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something to get you started, based upon the Porphyrin example from the gallery in `chemfig`'s manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  a-?[a]=[::+63]*5(
    -N?[b]=(
      -(-[::63]d)=[::-54]*5(
        -N?[c]-(
          =(-[::63]g)-[::-54]*5(
            =N?[d]-(
              =(-[::63]j)-[::-54]*5(
                -N(-[::-54,1.5]Fe?[b,,dotted]?[c]?[d,,dotted])
                -[,,1]?[a]=(-[::-54]l)-(-k)=
              )
            )
            -(-i)=(-h)-
          )
        )
        -(-f)=(-e)-
      )
    )
    -(-c)=(-b)-
  )
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ clemens: thank you very much. i updated the post because there a still some things i can't get. do you have any help? thx